# Expand only one table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm using jQuery to expand a row in a table when the row is clicked. How do I modify the code so that when another row is clicked, the currently open row collapses?

Here is the table:

```
<table class="tb">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="parent"><td>Click here</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hidden row</td></tr>
  <tr class="parent"><td>Or click here</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Another hidden row</td></tr>
 </tbody>    
</table>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('table.tb').each(function() {
 var $table = $(this);
 $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();
 });
 var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
});
```

Comment: are you expanding the rows next to `tr.parent` rows (the ones containing *hidden* text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to hide each parent on click

http://jsfiddle.net/ugwfQ/1/

```
$(".parent").children("td").click(function() {
    $(".parent").next("tr").hide();
    $(this).parent().next("tr").show();
});
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Is it possible to tweak that function so that it also hides the visible <tr> when that <tr> is clicked on (ie: instead of using _show()_, use _toggle()_?

Comment: Got it! Just changed the click to refer to the <tr> not the <td> $('.parent').click(function() { $('.parent').not(this).next('tr').hide();
$(this).next('tr').toggle();
});